# How to add colour change to the strobe coding?

Tags: arduino-nano

I have this strobe effect working. However, I would like to change the colour of the LEDs after each 'strobe sequence'. How can it be achieved?
The code I am using is this one:

```
    // Basic code NeoPixel 
    // wwww.arduinoplatform.com
    
    #include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>
    #ifdef __AVR__
     #include <avr/power.h> // Required for 16 MHz Adafruit Trinket
    #endif
    
    // Which pin on the Arduino is connected to the NeoPixels?
    // On a Trinket or Gemma we suggest changing this to 1:
    #define LED_PIN    6
    
    // How many NeoPixels ar
    Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(60, 6, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);
    
    void setup() {
      strip.begin();
      strip.show(); // Initialize all pixels to 'off'
    }
    
    // *** REPLACE FROM HERE ***
    
    void loop() {
      // Slower:
      // Strobe(0xff, 0x77, 0x00, 10, 100, 1000);
      // Fast:
      Strobe(0xFF, 0x00, 0xF8, 10, 50, 1000);
    }
    
    void Strobe(byte red, byte green, byte blue, int StrobeCount, int FlashDelay, int EndPause){
      for(int j = 0; j < StrobeCount; j++) {
        setAll(red,green,blue);
        showStrip();
        delay(FlashDelay);
        setAll(0,0,0);
        showStrip();
        delay(FlashDelay);
      }
     
     delay(EndPause);
    }
    
    // *** REPLACE TO HERE ***
    
    void showStrip() {
     #ifdef ADAFRUIT_NEOPIXEL_H
       // NeoPixel
       strip.show();
     #endif
     
    }
    
    void setPixel(int Pixel, byte red, byte green, byte blue) {
     #ifdef ADAFRUIT_NEOPIXEL_H
       // NeoPixel
       strip.setPixelColor(Pixel, strip.Color(red, green, blue));
     #endif
    }
    
    void setAll(byte red, byte green, byte blue) {
      for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++ ) {
        setPixel(i, red, green, blue);
      }
      showStrip();
    }
```

Comment: change the first three parameters in `Strobe(0xFF, 0x00, 0xF8, 10, 50, 1000);`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to cycle through a list of defined colors with your strobe effect. For that you can save the colors in a 2-dimensional array and then cycle through the array with a for loop. The 2-dimensional array is then a group of colors, each defined by the 3 numbers for a RGB value. Somewhat like this:

```
#define NUM_COLORS   5
byte colors[NUM_COLORS][3] = {
    {0xFF, 0, 0},
    {0, 0xFF, 0},
    {0, 0, 0xFF},
    {0xFF, 0xFF, 0},
    {0, 0xFF, 0xFF}
};

void loop(){
    for(int i=0;i<NUM_COLORS;i++){
        Strobe(colors[i][0], colors[i][1], colors[i][2], 10, 50, 1000);
    }
}
```

Note, that this is not a complete code, but only the interesting parts. You can incorporate this into your code. You can change the number of colors and the colors itself to your liking (I only took some example values, that are easy to recognize).